# Understanding Residuals vs Leverage plot in terms of meeting regression assumptions

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals, linear, leverage, cooks-distance

[image: Regression diagnostic plots]

Can someone help me understand the Residuals vs Leverage plot in terms of meeting the assumption of independence/influence for multiple linear regression models?

My understanding is that the observations of 19, 62 and 64 are extreme but nay not necessarily be considered influential. I understand that the spread of residuals in this plot should be even, but clearly this spread decreases as leverage increases - I'm not sure what this may mean in terms of influential points. I'm also aware that Cook's distance (indicated by red dashed line) is used to determine the influence of a value. But I'm not sure how to interpret this line on my plot with respect to the three extreme values of 19, 62 and 64. Furthermore, I'm baffled by the observation of 0.5 at the top right of the plot. It appears to be somehow connected to the Cook's distance line... but I'm really not sure at all how to interpret this 0.5 value. However, I do know that influential points tend to be located at the upper right or lower right corner of Residuals vs Leverage plots so I'm curious to about this value (0.5) in particular.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.